# Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using WinHost.com to host my site. The SQL Database/membership system works perfectly on my local computer, but when uploaded to the server it doesn't work. I've followed all steps correctly. And I have contacted support for my service but it's been over 2weeks and no reply.

I keep getting this error when i try to login or register a new user on my membership page on my site.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1953274
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849707
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +204
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider, SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32& schemaVersionCheck) +378
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection connection) +89
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +815
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +42
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +78
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +119
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4200; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016
```

Can somebody please tell me why this error has occured (obviously it can't find something...), and how I can fix it?

Thank you all

Bael

Comment: Is it possible that you need to further qualify the stored proc name or the owner is not dbo

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Did you run [`aspnet_regsql.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/x28wfk74(v=vs.100)#installing-the-database-using-aspnet_regsqlexe) against WinHost.com's sql server?

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

If you don't know where to run above command then you can simply run 'aspnet_regsql.exe' executable file.

In order to locate this file open your RUN Command Box by pressing Windows Key + r and put below command in that `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and Hit enter then find 'aspnet_regsql.exe' file. It will open a wizard that you can follow to resolve this error.

This error mostly occurs when you didn't enabled Roles in your asp.net mvc project At starting  before aspnet identity table automatically created.

You will need to make sure you run this so that the tables and objects are created on WinHost.com's SQL server.

Comment: If you have integrated security, use "-E" flag instead of "-U" (username) and "-P"(password) flags.

Comment: THANKYOU!!! Just to add, you can run this with no command line args to get a GUI, not quite as haxxor but does the job :)

Comment: @gabriel How to run aspnet_regsql.exe?

Comment: @IvorySantos: If you were asking about the usual path for the executable, it is e.g. "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319". See "Finding the Correct Version of Aspnet_regsql.exe" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.ASPX

Comment: @Jam Vile: selecting the correct exe that linked to will pull up the wizard, which will help you walk through this, if needed.

Comment: What does aspnet_regsql.exe do exactly? I've restored the database from a backup to my local sqlexpress, so it already has all of the tables and procs and such from the backup. Why would running this make a difference? Is there some under-the-hood magic that this does?

Comment: There is also a "Native Tools Command Prompt" shortcut that will open cmd window in the correct path under the Start Menu for Visual Studio or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts" (2013 version).

Comment: How come this isn't generated automatically by Entity Framework? My database inherits from IdentityDbContext, I thought this would enable ASP.NET Membership

Answer (score 30):

Open visual studio command prompt from the Visual studio tools folder from the start menu
and type 
`aspnet_regsql`

and follow the wizard to register the database for asp.net membership and role providers.

Comment: Hi mate, running aspnet_regsql I was able to fix my issue and now the question is what this --aspnet_regsql -- Do?

Answer (score 10):

I've seen this before. The database you are using doesn't have the required database elements for the membership, role management and profile features. So you've got a couple of options:

1. Copy across the tables, stored procedures & views from your local SQL Server using SQL Management Studio or a similar application
2. Use the [aspnet_regsql.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) to install the scripts from anew as per the instructions in this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2005/11/26/431597.aspx) *(I don't believe you can use the tool against a remote database if it's locked down. So you'll have to export the scripts and run them manually)*

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem- i copy/paste connectionString from `SQL Object manager` in Visual Studio and forget to type `Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName`.

Comment: I had `Initial Catalog=master` instead of `Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Check the schema the stored procedure belongs to on your host - it could be that it's not in the "dbo" schema.

e.g.
if it's within SomeOtherSchema, your call would need to be "SomeOtherSchema.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion"

Comment: Thank you AdaTheDev. Can you please tell me how I would go about changing the call to something else? Like, where abouts in the code would it be... web.config?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error when I had enabled `<roleManager>` believing I was enabling ASP.NET Identity 2. **They are not the same!** The `<roleManager>` enabled an old version of identity management which uses a different table structure to ASP.NET Identity 2 (which doesn't need "enabling" by the way - it's just there).

If you are intentionally using the old role-manager and still getting the error you might be looking at the default `localdb` instead of your database, in which case you can modify `<roleManager>` to point at any connection string you want:

```
  <roleManager
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      defaultProvider="OurSqlRoleProvider"
     >
      <providers>
          <add
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             applicationName="/"
             name="OurSqlRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>

  </roleManager>
```

If you are are after using ASP.NET Identity 2, here's an article on it:
http://johnatten.com/2014/04/20/asp-net-mvc-and-identity-2-0-understanding-the-basics/

Answer (score 1):

In short you should recompile the aspnet provider dll using the sql username you were assigned from your hosting.

- Download the
  http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi
- Replace from the source code all the
  references to dbo with your hosting
  database username
- Compile (you need Visual Studio) and
  place the
  ProviderToolkitSampleProviders.dll in
  the Bin folder
- In your web.config replace the "type"
  attribute of every line with
  “Microsoft.Samples.,
  ProviderToolkitSampleProviders”
- Replace in you local sql server all dbo references with your hosting database username
- Export the sql object creation script and run them on the remote database
- Copy the records from your local sql table aspnet_SchemaVersions to the remote database

Another option, pheraps simpler to try, is to replace the dbo references in your local sql server database with your hosting database username, then upload and attach your mdf file.

Hope it helps

Thomas

Comment: huh? what color is the sky in your world? lolzalot. Dude just needs to provision his database or fix his connection string. No answer would have been better than this.

Comment: Ooops when he wrote "I've followed all steps correctly" I thought he already tried aspnet_regsql.exe and doublechecked the connection string. A hosting provider I know doesn't permit aspnet_regsql.exe so mine is a working solution for that case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add to the web.config file

```
  <modules>
          <remove name="RoleManager" />

</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Gabriel McAdams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213474/gabriel-mcadams) mentioned, I used `aspnet_regsql.exe` but because I am using `Integrated Security=True` in the connection string I used different flags and also note that the -S flag refers to the SQL Server instance name (in my case `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`) instead of the server name:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regsql  -S DBInstanceName -E -A all -d DBName
```