# Invalid object name dbo.Quizs

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

Every thing was working fine, when I publish my Visual studio 2013 project on Azure, it start giving me this error: `Invalid object name dbo.Quizs`. [Link](http://bcsf11m023.azurewebsites.net/Quiz) to published site. What i am missing here ? I am new at azure deployment that is why need well explained and easy solution. Read this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162631/invalid-object-name-dbo-tablename) stack overflow post but not understand well what should I do ?
Regards.

Comment: Access the database through SQL Managment studio using credentials specified in the connection string and check if the database has table named Quizs or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue recently. My problem was that I set up my Azure Database separate from my Azure Web Site (for the Web API). As a result, though I had the correct connectionstring in my web.config, when I went to the Azure Management Portal Config section for the website, the only connectionstring present was "default connection". I added the correction connectionstring in the management portal, and I added the correct database as a "Linked Resource" in the management portal. This may fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your connection String, you are missing Database =  or initial catalog = . Also make sure you have moved your database and its objects successfully.