# When I use the Roles object I get an error of "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'"

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider

So, I have been searching all over the internet for a solution. I've done a lot of research and it has only left me more lost. I am creating an MVC 5 site for Azure and I am having trouble setting up Role Management.

When I use the Roles object I get an error of "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'"  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165908/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion) link but I don't know how it would apply to Azure.

My web.config file is currently set up like this.

```
<add name="RoleDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Techdb3.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="RoleDB"
     name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
     applicationName="TechAndGames" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: And you use Web Sites, or Web Role?! And how did you initialize this database (techdb3)?

Comment: I believe I may not know what Web roles are compare to web sites. The database is code first and I simply point it at my Azure MS SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MVC 5, you need to remove the `roleManager` tag, I think. I was using `<roleManager>` in my latest MVC 5 application and was getting the exact same error as you. As soon as I removed it, the error went away. I think this is because MVC uses a different role management approach.

A couple of other things: make sure you have the proper tables setup in your database. These are the tables you will need:

- _MigrationHistory
- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

You may not need all of these, depending on what you are doing. To get these setup properly, I (1) created a new project with the MVC 5 template, (2) ran the project locally (3) went through the registration process of a new user on the site and (4) looked in my local SQL server (LocalDb)\v11.0 and it had created a database there with all the tables I mention above. I then scripted those tables out and ran the scripts against my real database.

Then, in your application you should be able to call `User` and get access to methods like `User.IsInRole("someRole");`.

Comment: I believe this was exactly my problem I forgot to update my findings. Yes if you keep the <roleManager> tag in the configuration I believe the server attempts to revert to an older version of "roleManger" which used to require a call to create all of the necessary tables.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :-)

Comment: I know this is old but it just saved me after several days of frustration trying to get my MVC 5 Identity project running on an 3rd party hosting server.