# ASP.NET Identity IsUserInRole throws Checkschema error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-identity, database-migration, roleprovider

I am working on User management for my site.

1)  I have created a VB.net webforms application in Visual Studio 2013.

2) I ran the site

3) registered a user

4) logged in using that user and all is great.

However, when I tried to display a message to see if the user was in admin role using

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "admin") Then
        rUser.Text = "You are not authorzied"
    Else
        rUser.Text = "WELCOME ADMIN"
    End If
End Sub
```

I get the following error when trying to login.  If I understand correctly, this is the old Membership Store Procedure that it is trying to find.  I have been looking for a couple of days and can't seem to figure out what is going on.  everything I see seems to "just work".

I know it's rude to point but if someone could point me in the right direction.  I have a feeling it's some simple...

[Schema Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCxWA.png)

NOTE: Just saw this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/29392043/3884800 apparently this is not an easy one... :S

**UPDATE: getting new error:**

[Roles not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB9hV.png)

Am I missing something in the App_Start???

Comment: Would I have to preform a migration using the Package Manager???

Comment: we had discussed similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165908/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion) go ahead.

Comment: Share your web config... may be i could help

Comment: Here is my webconfig.  I have read that this is only for the old membership, and that Identity is set in the App_Start somewhere???


<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="connString" applicationName="HondaCanada" />
       
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

Comment: hemantsharma, is this not for the old membership system, not for Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity has own Role Manager therefor `Roles` class dose not work when using Identity. So if you want check if a user in role or not simply write something like this:

To check current user use:

```
User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

To check another user:

```
Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
manager.IsInRole("UserID", "Admin")
```

Comment: YAAAAHOOOOO!!!!  Many many thank you's you rock.  I have been struggling with this for some time..  many thanks @Sam Farajpour Ghamari