# What do I miss in my web.config if the error dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion occures?

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

```
Source Error: 


Line 52: 
Line 53:                 ' ***** START *****
Line 54:                 If Page.User.IsInRole("tco_admin") Or Page.User.IsInRole("admin") Or _
Line 55:                    Page.User.IsInRole("tco_laboratory_logistics_lab") Or _
Line 56:                    Page.User.IsInRole("tco_laboratory_logistics_sample") Or _
```

What do I miss in my web.cofig if it displays this error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Googling your error is always a good start. Here you have two solved solutions to the exaxt same error.. SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165908/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion , MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/7a85cf72-7f53-421f-be74-b12262c47f37/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dboaspnetcheckschemaversion?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: The 'System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1' :(