# ConnectionStrings where do they come from? Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm running a Razor site on Azure with an Azure SQL Database, but have started getting a connection error message saying it can't connect to a App_Data localdb - which I don't use. I also have noticed my project kindly recreated a localdb without me asking it to at some point. I've migrated the Asp identity tables to my the azure sql database so it's all happily in one place (was this a good idea? seemed it to me). Anyway. The localdb message confused me as, as far as I know, there is no reference to the localdb in my project. My web.config has 2 connection strings:

I've checked these with Kudu and that is what is on the site's actual web.config - so no transformations or publishing connection strings are there. YET if I debug azure and look at 
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` I see 4 connection strings, not 2. The last 2 are from my web.config, the 2nd is blank and the 1st reads as:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}
```

I can't help but wonder how and where this is being used?

However watching `ConfigurationManager.ConnecitonStrings[DefaultConnection]` *is* correct. And my db model initialises like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    ...
```

So that's fairly uneventful. It may be worth mentioning that I was trying to enable site-wide SSL when it all went tits up like this. I've removed that code yet the problem persists :(

Here's more about the error I'm seeing:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.
>   The provider attempted to automatically create the application
>   services database because the provider determined that the database
>   does not exist.

my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=tcp:myweb.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=mywebtest;user id=myStdMobile;password=dfdfd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <add name="DeveloperConnection" connectionString="data source=tcp:myweb.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=mywebtest;user id=myWebDbAdmin;password=fdfd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mydbstorage;AccountKey=7Ukljdslkjasdfjkdasfkj==" />

  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

<roleManager 
    enabled="true" 
    cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
</roleManager>

      <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="3600" />
      <globalization culture="en-GB" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="PdfSharp" publicKeyToken="f94615aa0424f9eb" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.32.2608.0" newVersion="1.32.2608.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

    <location path="answers">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="audits">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="candidates">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="vCandidateTables">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="members.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="documents">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="members.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="companies">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="questions">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="users">
        <system.web>
            <authorization configSource="myadmin.config" />
        </system.web>
    </location>

</configuration>
```

**An update**
It is the rolemanager that my error - if I disable it the problem goes away ... along with role management, but still! It's a step...

Comment: What's in your `machine.config`?

Comment: I don't think Azure has one, does it?

Comment: it has, but these are stripped. Can you post your web.config here. These are the default connections string entries the Visual Studio project wizard sets up while you create new application. They can be hidden in configuration sections for EntityFramework itself.

Comment: ok. added. Also note that I've narrowed it down to rolemanager being enabled. I thought that if I used migrations to create a new database that it would create everything I needed in the new location for role management ... apparently not!

Comment: Have you checked 'myadmin,config' and 'members.config' ?

Comment: yep - they just check for membership in a role within asp identity

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was that I had `<roleManager>` enabled believing I was referring to ASP.NET Identity 2. **They are not the same!** The `<roleManager>` enabled an old version of identity management and then the `<roleManager>` element defaults to a `localdb`. So ... this is where the extra connection string comes from. Here is how the `<roleManager>` looks in the effective machine.config from Azure (note the `providers -> connectionStringName`):

```
<roleManager 
   enabled="false" 
   cacheRolesInCookie="false" 
   cookieName=".ASPXROLES" 
   cookieTimeout="30" 
   cookiePath="/" 
   cookieRequireSSL="false" 
   cookieSlidingExpiration="true" 
   cookieProtection="All" 
   defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
   createPersistentCookie="false" 
   maxCachedResults="25">
   <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
         connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
         applicationName="/" 
         name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add 
         applicationName="/" 
         name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Once I found this I updated my web.config to point to my database, like so:

```
  <roleManager
      enabled="true"
      cacheRolesInCookie="true"
      defaultProvider="OurSqlRoleProvider"
     >
      <providers>
          <add
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             applicationName="/"
             name="OurSqlRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>

  </roleManager>
```

... but this simply generated a new error of 
[Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165908/could-not-find-stored-procedure-dbo-aspnet-checkschemaversion) THIS was because rolemanager is for an old form of asp identity and not ASP.NET Identity 2.

(A small point, but the way I found this error was simply going back through source control, rebuilding, and seeing which change broke it.)